# How to run FE regressions for time-invariant subgroups (in Stata)

Tags: loops, regression, stata

Hi run several fixed effects regressions on several outcomes, which I store in a `local` and go through in a `foreach` loop. Next I want to add subgroup analysis by stable, time-invariant trait (such as gender or race). Thus I cannot use a `bysort group: regress`

Following is a MWE, how can I redo this analysis for all 3 levels of `race`? At the moment I do a copy-paste, preserve the data and keep levels each one at a time. I hope that there's a more efficient way.

```
* load data
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/nlswork

* set panel structure
xtset idcode year

* fixed effects regression 
local outcomes "ln_wage ttl_exp tenure" 
local rhsvars "c.wks_ue##c.wks_ue##i.occ_code union age i.year 1.race"

foreach o of local outcomes { 
        quietly xtreg `o' `rhsvars', i(idcode) fe 
                margins, dydx(wks_ue) at(occ_code=(1 2 3)) post
                outreg2 using report_`r'.doc, word append ctitle(`o')
} 
* subgroup analysis race (or gender) ??
```

Comment: What is wrong with `if race == 1` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pearly Spencer mentioned above, `if` seems like the perfect solution. (I assumed your local macro `r` was for iterating over values of race.)

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/nlswork
xtset idcode year
local outcomes "ln_wage ttl_exp tenure" 
local rhsvars "c.wks_ue##c.wks_ue##i.occ_code union age i.year"
levelsof race
local racelevels `r(levels)'

foreach r in `racelevels'{
    foreach o of local outcomes { 
            quietly xtreg `o' `rhsvars' if race == `r', i(idcode) fe 
                    margins, dydx(wks_ue) at(occ_code=(1 2 3)) post
                    outreg2 using report_`r'.doc, word append ctitle(`o')
    }
}
```

By the way, consider the user-written command `reghdfe` by Sergio Correia as a faster and more intuitive substitute for xtreg: http://scorreia.com/software/reghdfe/

(Code edited)